# MediaUriElement cannot render

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

```
VideoControl= this.Template.FindName("MediaPlayer", this) as MediaUriElement;
var source = "url that can play video"
VideoControl.Source = new Uri(source);  
VideoControl.Play();
```

And I got a exception: ”could not render any streams from the source Uri“
I don't have this problem on my development machine, but it happens on the client machine. how to solve

Display the video normally

Comment: Not enough info to answer your question. What exactly is your `source`... Is it a file on your computer or is it a file from the internet? Does the client have access to the same file? What is the file format? (maybe it's a missing codec issue). **PS**: Use the [edit post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76796312/edit) option to add any extra info to your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.